# upper_bound and find giving different results

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am new to STL and used `find()` and `upper_bound()` functions on vector to find the position of 6 . The code is given below

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> sam ={1,2,5,3,7,8,4,6};
    int f=upper_bound(sam.begin(), sam.end(), 6)- sam.begin();

    vector<int>::iterator it; 
    it =find (sam.begin(), sam.end(), 6);
    int d=it - sam.begin() ;
    cout<<d<<" "<<f<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output when you run the code is 7 4 ,while I expected it to be 7 7 .
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `std::upper_bound` (and `std::lower_bound`, for that matter) require that the range being searched must be **sorted**. (That's an oversimplification, but it should be enough to get you going).

Comment: [This `std::upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) and [this `std:lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) references might be helpful.

Comment: What if the data in the container have been created or inserted at run-time from an external source (user, file, network, etc.)? Then you don't know the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cppreference.com for `std::upper_bound()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) explains it nicely (emphasis mine):

> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range [first, last) that is *greater* than value, or last if no such element is found.
>
> **The range [first, last) must be partitioned with respect to the
>   expression `!(value < element)` or `!comp(value, element)`, i.e., all
>   elements for which the expression is `true` must precede all elements
>   for which the expression is `false`. A fully-sorted range meets this
>   criterion.**

In your case, you have a 7 (greater than 6, at index 4) appearing *before* a 4 (which is equal or less than 6), so the precondition is not met.

The idea of `std::upper_bound()` and its companions is to quickly do binary searches in sorted arrays. As opposed to linear search as in `std::find()`, it only needs O(log(n)) time complexity instead of O(n).

Comment: then what is the most efficient way to find 6 in this vector if I dont use 'find' since it takes linear time

Comment: If your array is not sorted, you _must_ use linear search, because an algorithm that does not analyze every element cannot know if the searched value appears _before_ or _after_ the currently checked element.